# JsHint error with analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, jshint

I am getting a bunch of errors on JsHint regarding my Google Analytics snippet.

How can I isolate this code so that JsHint ignores it? I guess this should be ignored by JsHint.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://www.jshint.com/docs/):

```
// Code here will be linted with JSHint.
/* jshint ignore:start */
// Code here will be linted with ignored by JSHint.
/* jshint ignore:end */
```